# Insert values with different types to MongoDB collection from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, sails-mongo

I'm using sails web framework with Node.js and MongoDB to create my own website. Right now, I'm facing some difficulties while trying to create a new user, and insert values (from different types: Number,Array,Object) to my 'users' collection, when sending a post request.
I can't figure it out, why the only type that works here is 'string', when I change the type to 'Number' for example, and send a post request via Postman, this is the error that pops up :

```
 "message": "Resolver error: \"age\" has wrong type",
    "name": "PARAMETER_WRONG_TYPE",
```

This is the user Controller :

```
create: function(req, res){
            var expectedInputs = [
            {
                name: 'idsid',
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            }
            ,
            {
                name: 'age',
                type: 'Number',
                required: true
            }
            ,
            {
                name: 'last_name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            }
                              ];

SanitizeService.allReqParams(req.allParams(), expectedInputs)
                .then(function(sanitizedInputs){
                    var user = {};
                    user.idsid = sanitizedInputs['idsid'];
                    user.age = sanitizedInputs['age'];
                    user.last_name = sanitizedInputs['last_name'];

                    return UserService.create(user);
                })
                .then(function(response){
                    res.ok(response);
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    res.badRequest(err);
                });

        }
```

This is the function create in UserService :

```
create: function(user) {
        return new P(function(resolve, reject){
            sails.log.verbose('API Audit: UserService.create called');
            var rejection = new Error('UserService.create Error: ');
            user.Created = new Date();
            user.Modified = new Date();
            Users.native(function(err, collection){
                if(err){
                    rejection.message += 'problem connecting to collection';
                    return reject(rejection);
                }
                collection.update({'idsid': user.idsid}, user, {upsert: true}, 
                    function(err, results){
                        if(err){
                            rejection.message += err;
                            return reject(rejection);
                        } else {
                            return resolve(results);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
      });
    }
```

Please let me know if there is anything else needed in order to understand the issue.
Appreciate your help!

**Edit :** 
As suggested below, I tried to change the type to "**integer**" and this is the error I get :

```
"stack": "Error: Resolver error: wrong type \"integer\"\n    at Resolver.addParameter (C:\\workspace\\node_modules\\input-resolver\\index.js:81:13)\n    at C:\\workspace\\api\\services\\SanitizeService.js:57:15\n    at Array.forEach (native)\n    at C:\\workspace\\api\\services\\SanitizeService.js:5
```

I'm not sure if this is necessary or not, but this is the **input-resolver** :

```
function ResolverError(msg, name) {
  this.message = msg;
  this.name = name;
}

ResolverError.prototype = new Error();

function Resolver() {
  this.parameters = [];
  this.asPromise = false;
}

Resolver.types = ['string', 'boolean', 'number', 'object', 'array'];

Resolver.checkType = function(param, type) {
  return type == 'array' ? Array.isArray(param) : typeof param === type;
};

Resolver.prototype.asPromise = function(asPromise)
{
    this.asPromise = (typeof asPromise == 'boolean') ? asPromise : true;
};

Resolver.prototype.getParameter = function(name, parent) {
  if (!this.parameters.length) {
    return null;
  }

  parent = typeof parent == 'string' && '' != parent ? parent : null;
  for (var i = 0, len = this.parameters.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (name === this.parameters[i].name) {
      if (parent && parent != this.parameters[i].parent) continue;

      return this.parameters[i];
    }
  }

  return null;
};

Resolver.prototype.getAllParameters = function() {
  return this.parameters;
};

Resolver.prototype.addParameter = function(param) {
  var checkParameter = function(param) {
    if (typeof param != 'object') {
      return false;
    }

    if (!param.name || typeof param.required != 'boolean') {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  if (!checkParameter(param)) {
    throw new ResolverError(
      'Resolver error: parameter not valid',
      'PARAMETER_NOT_VALID'
    );
  }

  var paramFound = this.getParameter(param.name, param.parent);
  if (null !== paramFound) {
      throw new ResolverError(
          'Resolver error: trying to overwrite "' + param.name + '" parameter',
          'PARAMETER_OVERWRITE'
      );
  }

  var p = {
    name: param.name,
    required: param.required,
    parent: null
  };

  if (typeof param.type != 'undefined') {
    if (Resolver.types.indexOf(param.type) == -1) {
      throw new Error('Resolver error: wrong type "' + param.type + '"');
    }

    p.type = param.type;
  }

  if (typeof param.default != 'undefined') {
    if (p.required) {
      throw new Error(
        'Resolver error: trying to set default value to required parameter'
      );
    }

    if (p.type && !Resolver.checkType(param.default, p.type)) {
      throw new Error(
        'Resolver error: default value doesn\'t match the param type'
      );
    }

    p.default = param.default;
  }

  if (typeof param.values != 'undefined') {
    if (!Array.isArray(param.values)) {
      throw new Error('Resolver error: available values is not an array');
    }

    if (!param.values.length) {
      throw new Error('Resolver error: available values array is empty');
    }

    p.values = param.values;
  }

  if (typeof param.parent == 'string') {
    if ('' == param.parent) {
        throw new Error(
          'Resolver error: parent property for "' + param.name +
          '" is an empty string'
        );
    }

    var parentParam = this.getParameter(param.parent);
    if (null !== parentParam) {
      if (parentParam.type && parentParam.type != 'object') {
        throw new Error(
          'Resolver error: parent for parameter "' + param.name + '"' +
          ' is defined, but has type of "' + parentParam.type + '" instead of' +
          ' "object"'
        );
      }

      parentParam.type = 'object';
      parentParam.required = true;
    } else {
      this.parameters.unshift({
        name: param.parent,
        required: true,
        type: 'object',
        parent: null
      });
    }

    p.parent = param.parent;
  }

  this.parameters.push(p);

  return this;
};

Resolver.prototype._resolve = function(data, callback) {
  var getKeys = function(obj) {
    if (typeof obj != 'object') {
      return [];
    }

    var keys = [];
    for (var k in obj) {
      keys.push(k);
    }

    return keys;
  };

  if (!this.parameters.length) {
    return callback(
      new ResolverError(
        'Resolver error: no parameters specified',
        'NO_RESOLVER_PARAMETERS'
      )
    );
  }

  if (!getKeys(data).length) {
    return callback(
      new ResolverError(
        'Resolver error: empty data provided',
        'EMPTY_DATA'
      )
    );
  }

  var resolved = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < this.parameters.length; i++) {
    var param = this.parameters[i];

    var parameterData = param.parent ? data[param.parent][param.name] :
      data[param.name]
    ;

    if (param.required) {
      if (typeof parameterData == 'undefined') {
        return callback(
          new ResolverError(
            'Resolver error: "' + param.name + '" required parameter not found',
            'NO_REQUIRED_PARAMETER'
          )
        );
      }
    } else {
      if (
        typeof parameterData == 'undefined' &&
        typeof param.default == 'undefined'
      ) {
        continue;
      }

      parameterData = typeof parameterData == 'undefined' ?
      param.default : parameterData;
    }

    if (
      typeof param.type == 'string' &&
      !Resolver.checkType(parameterData, param.type)
    ) {
      return callback(
        new ResolverError(
          'Resolver error: "' + param.name + '" has wrong type',
          'PARAMETER_WRONG_TYPE'
        )
      );
    }

    if (param.values && param.values.indexOf(parameterData) == -1) {
      return callback(
        new ResolverError(
          'Resolver error: "' + param.name + '" has wrong value',
          'PARAMETER_WRONG_VALUE'
        )
      );
    }

    if (param.parent) {
      resolved[param.parent][param.name] = parameterData;
    } else {
      resolved[param.name] = parameterData;
    }
  }

  return callback(null, resolved);
};

Resolver.prototype.resolve = function(data, callback) {
    this._resolve(data, callback);
};

Resolver.prototype.resolvePromise = function(inputData) {
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        _this._resolve(inputData, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return fulfill(data);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = Resolver;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be using sails mongo for interacting with mongo db as you mentioned this is a sails project.

Sails models do not provide **Number** type it instead provides integer and float.

Data types supported by sails models are :

- string
- text
- integer
- float
- date
- datetime
- boolean
- binary
- array
- json
- mediumtext
- longtext
- objectid

Please check this:
http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes
You might want to change type from Number to int.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, my original post was edited according to this suggestion.

Comment: I would like to know if you have referred to some documentation or tutorial relevant to sails mongo, because you are complicating the code for a scenario of adding a user to mongo using sails. Please refer this link and tell me if it is different than your requirement. I suggest you go through this documentation : http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm :)